# MySQL Distance Between Point and Circle

Tags: mysql, geometry, geolocation, geospatial, spatial

**My aim is to calculate the minimum distance between a point and a circle** (defined by a point and a radius). This problem is also definde a [shortest distance between a point and a circle](https://www.varsitytutors.com/hotmath/hotmath_help/topics/shortest-distance-between-a-point-and-a-circle).

Also described as 'D' at the image:

[image: Distance calculation]

First off the bat, i worked on distance between two points and got this query working as intended.

```
select st_distance_sphere(
POINT(-27.3449,33.7501), 
POINT( 22.6761,45.7442)
)
```

This returns me distance between these two points. But i want to calculate distance between a point and a circle. Parameters I have is:

```
point1_lat, point1_long, point2_lat, point2_long, point2_radius (in meters)
```

Is there a magic function for this in MySQL or should i resort to manual calculation using mathematical means.

Every opinion counts. Thank you

Comment: Probably you'll need to type the formula yourself. Doesn't look too daunting.

Comment: you have to implement the function yourself https://www.varsitytutors.com/hotmath/hotmath_help/topics/shortest-distance-between-a-point-and-a-circle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something as simple as

`GREATEST(st_distance_sphere(circle_center, point) - circle_radius, 0)`

should work.

This computes distance between center of the circle and the point, the minimum distance between circle and point is less by circle_radius. We then make sure it is non-negative (if the point is within circle).

Comment: It worked. There is a syntax error with the parentheses, please consider editing for future reference.